# MemSQL - unable to connect remotely to EC2 cluster using MySQL client

Tags: amazon-ec2, remote-access, singlestore

I have used http://cloud.memsql.com to successfully deploy a MemSQL cluster to EC2 as documented here: http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/setup/setup_cloud/.

I can SSH to the master aggregator, and successfully login to the MemSQL prompt locally. However, I cannot connect remotely using a MySQL client application.

I have double-checked port 3306 is open and just for testing have applied all privileges to root:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The documentation states:

> Once your cluster is up and running, connect to the master aggregator using any valid MySQL client driver.

Can anyone advise on a step I have missed?

--

UPDATE 1 - The source range is open for the MemSQL port:

```
3306    tcp 0.0.0.0/0
```

UPDATE 2 - ufw has been disabled for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a DNS issue by the provider I was using. Tried connecting using a cell phone and had no issues.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!  That is a pretty frustrating bug.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, clusters spun up by cloud.memsql.com lock down their security group to the vpc for the MemSQL ports (like 3306).  If you want to access it from outside of the vpc, you will need to add a new rule to the group.  Something like this would open the group completely:

Add an Ingress rule for port 3306-3306 for CIDR: 0.0.0.0/0

Note that this will open the cluster to the world, and anyone will be able to connect.  Instead of 0.0.0.0/0, I recommend using your public ip and a /32 like so: YOUR_IP/32

Comment: Many thanks - yes I spotted this and opened up the source range to 0.0.0.0/0. I even added all tcp just for a test but still cannot connect.